# add a new counter index variable to a netcdf file that increases with time

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I want to add a new variable to an existing netcdf file which simply increases linearly with the time variable of file, that is to say, on the first time slice the variable has the number 1 everywhere, on the second timeslice it is set to 2, etc.

I know how to open the file in python or fortran and define and add the variable and write out the modified file, but I was hoping that there might be a quick and easy way to do this from the command line using **nco** or **cdo**.  I also wondered if I could do it by dumping the file to CDL format with **ncdump**, hacking it and turning it back to netcdf with **ncgen**, but that seemed more longwinded and problematic than the python approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1-D array use this

```
ncap2 -s 'var=array(1,1,$time)' in.nc out.nc
```

For multi-dimensional arrays just add that to the zero-array

```
ncap2 -s 'var=array(0,0,/$time,$lat,$lon/)+array(1,1,$time)' in.nc out.nc
```

The numeric type of the array is determined by the type of the first argument to the array function. See the [manual](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#array) on `array()` for details.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered (two years after asking!) that there is also a `cdo` function `seq` that produces an incrementing timeseries.  The file produced is for a single point so you then need to `enlarge` the field  to match the target grid and finally `merge` with the original file:

```
# in the follow $n is the number of timeslices in in.nc 
cdo -f nc4 seq,1,$n seq.nc 
cdo enlarge,in.nc seq.nc seq2d.nc # enlarge to in.nc grid
cdo merge in.nc seq2d.nc out.nc   # and merge
```

you can pipe this all into one command in the following way:

```
cdo merge in.nc -enlarge,in.nc -seq,1,$n out.nc
```

The `nco` solution is great, but I think I may find this easier to remember.